# Math calculation on esc_html elements

Tags: php

I have 2 `esc_html` elements in my code. I want to make some math calculation using that.

The codes are as follows:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $referral_stats['click'] ); ?>

<?php echo esc_html( $referral_stats['conv_rate']  );?>
```

And it is printing the correct output.

But I want to multiply those 2 outputs and divide 100 with the result. So I tried this:

```
(<?php echo esc_html( $referral_stats['click'] ); ?> * <?php echo esc_html( $referral_stats['conv_rate']  );?>)/100
```

But it is printing the values with the multiplication and division sign.

Can anyone please let me know how to get the output print instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Move the math inside of `esc_html`

Comment: Do the maths first, _then_ escape the final result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I got that working using this final code:

```
<?php                           
    $final_click = $referral_stats['click'];
    $final_rate =  $referral_stats['conv_rate'];
    $final_regd = ($final_click * $final_rate)/100;
?>  
<td><?php echo esc_html( $final_regd ); ?> </td>
```

Thanks.